# Sending data to two different fields using foreign key

Tags: django

I am using foreign key of a model person using both its field in other other model company. But while inserting data in company I am not getting last name, output is employee and last are both the same.

Class Person (models.Model):

```
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.first_name)
```

Class Company (models.Model):

```
name=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
employee=models.ForeignKey(Person,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='first',null=True)
last=models.ForeignKey(Person,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='second',null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name)
```

## ViewSet

class CompanyViewset(viewsets.ViewSet):

```
def create(self,request):
    name=request.data.get('name')
    employee=request.data.get('employee')
    last=request.data.get('last')
    user=Company()
    user.name=name
    user.employee=Person.objects.get(first_name=employee)
    user.last=Person.objects.get(last_name=last)

    #print(user.last)
    #user.last=use.last_name

    print(user.last.last_name)
    user.save()

    return Response({'Successfully saved'})
```

Comment: It sounds like `employee` and `last` are pointing to the same Person object.

Comment: yes,while posting diffrent data in employee and last i am getting the self.first_name

Comment: you forgot to add django-rest-framework tag.  And I don t understand what problem you have. Can you explain with more detalis?

Comment: you receive `employee` and `last` in the viewset but don t save?

Comment: i have inserted data in person class first_name=Ashutosh,las_name=Mishra,now in company class ,in employee i am sending Ashutosh and in last i am sending Mishra but in admin i am getting only Ashutosh in both employee and last

Comment: why you need two different foreign key for that?  `employee` and `last` is not the same person?

Comment: i am learning django,i want to do this ,this kind of situation may occur if we need to use multiple firlds for other model

Comment: how it is possible?

Comment: How can i do this